# Why am I getting an error when stopping ColdFusion 11 service in Windows 2012?

Tags: service, coldfusion

Stopping ColdFusion 11 service via the Windows Services console takes a very long time, and eventually errors out. It eventually stops (after several minutes).

When I attempt to stop the service on the command line using `net stop ColdFusion 11 Application Server", I get the following response:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net stop "ColdFusion 11 Application Server"
The ColdFusion 11 Application Server service is stopping........................
................................................
A system error has occurred.

System error 170 has occurred.

The requested resource is in use.

The ColdFusion 11 Application Server service was stopped successfully.
```

I have been unable to find any more information about this error. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can prevent it (in case I need to quickly restart the service)?

Comment: I've not seen it in 11, but that happens all the time with 9. I dunno what causes it, as I never needed to care, but you can simply kill the tomcat process if a normal shutdown doesn't work. I just think the shutdown process of CF is flaky.